# Strip out region prefix in url ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string

I'm looping through an array where i am parsing certain linkedin URL's. I need to do some in place array modification when I come across a linkedin url which is of the format 'http://ca.linkedin.com/in/stratta' to 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/stratta'. Need some help on the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `link` is variable which is holding your url. Then try this in your loop

```
'http://www.' + link.split('//')[1].split('.')[1..-1].join('.')
```

Hope this helps.